# No package 'xcb-xrm' found

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm trying to install [awesome 4.0](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/documentation/01-readme.md.html). To install all the dependencies I ran `sudo apt-get build-dep awesome`. If I run make in my awesome directory there are some libs still missing:

```
$ make
Running cmake…
-- git not found.
-- asciidoc -> /usr/bin/asciidoc
-- xmlto -> /usr/bin/xmlto
-- gzip -> /bin/gzip
-- ldoc -> /usr/bin/ldoc
-- convert -> /usr/bin/convert
-- Checking for modules 'glib-2.0;gdk-pixbuf-2.0;cairo;x11;xcb-cursor;xcb-randr;xcb-xtest;xcb-xinerama;xcb-shape;xcb-util>=0.3.8;xcb-keysyms>=0.3.4;xcb-icccm>=0.3.8;xcb-xkb;xkbcommon;xkbcommon-x11;cairo-xcb;libstartup-notification-1.0>=0.10;xproto>=7.0.15;libxdg-basedir>=1.0.0;xcb-xrm'
--   No package 'xcb-xrm' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  awesomeConfig.cmake:153 (pkg_check_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (include)
```

I checked which package I have to install to close this gap `apt-cache search xcb-xrm` but I got no results. Then I checked the dependencies list from awesome, there is only a entry `xcb-util-xrm` so I was looking for apt-cache search xcb-util-xrm`. I got also no results. How to install the missing library?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: What distro and version are you using?

Comment: @steeldriver ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: As far as I can see, the package did not become available until 16.10: see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xcb-xrm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: @steeldriver that means I have to build and install from source?

Comment: @Hölderlin this seems to have been answered. Do you still want it migrated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned by steeldriver, the package is not available until 16.10.

One option is to built it manually from source ([github](https://github.com/Airblader/xcb-util-xrm))

A Second option would be to get it from a 3rd party ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aguignard/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xcb-util-xrm
```

Comment: how do you find this third party ppa?

Comment: Google "[package] site:launchpad.net", click on the first result and scroll down to the end of the page and look for the green text that says "Other versions of '[package]' in untrusted archives", click on it and it will reveal a list of all ppa's containing the package

Comment: I did this, but no luck. `E: Unable to locate package xcb-util-xrm`. Trying to compile awesomewm in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get install libxcb-xrm-dev` instead

Answer (score 11):

It seems like the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xrm-dev
```

instead of:

```
sudo apt-get install xcb-util-xrm
```

Comment: Always better to use a standard package whenever you can.  I found that this is now available on 17.10.  Thanks Akhi.

Comment: I did this, but no luck. `E: Unable to locate package libxcb-xrm-dev`. Trying to compile awesomewm in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I did some Google search and according to https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/Compiling-&-Installing, it seems like you need to grab it from a ppa.  Hope this helps.